# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier with a for..of loop in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i run this code with  : node app.js
I get this error:

```
/home/app.js:48
    for (var k of occurrences) {
               ^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
```

Link to the file  https://github.com/Hypertopic/Cassandre/blob/master/node/app.js

Comment: this is due to your version of node.js, upgrade to version 0.12+ (4+ recommended)

Comment: @eltonkamami — http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-for..of_loops says they are supported from 0.12 up

Comment: What version of Node are you using?

Comment: @Quentin thanks for reminding me about 0.12, i always go and mention 4+ as it being the active LTS

Comment: I'm astonished that pre-0.12 is still around anywhere.

Comment: i am using v0.10.25

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, you have to use node 0.12+, as `for..of` loops are not implemented in 0.10. http://node.green/#for--of-loops

Some related features might have to be enabled specifically via `--harmony` or `--es_staging` command-line flag.